# If two sequences converge to the same number, with one decreasing to the limit, does it eventually have to "overtake" the other?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm doing an exercise in real analysis, asking whether $(a_n) \to 1$ implies that $(a_n^n)$ is bounded.
I think it's true and in trying to prove it, I wondered if one could say:

If $(b_n) \to 1$, $b_{n+1} \le b_n$, $b_n > 1$ $\forall n$ and $(a_n) \to 1$ then $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ $a_{n+N} < b_n$

Since then I could say that any sequence going to 1 is eventually less than $(1+1/n)^n$ which is bounded. 
I'm not sure about the statement. I tried "proving" it by contradiction, but I'm getting confused by the order of quantifiers and I'm not making any progress.
Is the statement true?
If yes, how can I prove it, if no, what is a counterexample?

Comment: Think about $a_n=\sqrt[n]{n}$

Comment: The statement you are wondering about does not look true either.  Suppose $a_n=b_{\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}$ so $a_{n^2}=b_{n}$

Comment: ah yes, should have thought of that counterxample. I meant $(1+1/n)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are right, the statement is true, but you are looking for something too complicated. It derives directly from the definition of convergence.

$(a_n) \rightarrow 1$ is equivalent, by definition, to saying :

For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exist $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $\vert a_n - 1\vert \leq \varepsilon$

The thing to see here is that you can fix $\varepsilon$. For example, take it equal to 1, or any other arbitrary strictly positive number.

By definition, there is a rank $N$ after which $\vert a_n - 1\vert \leq \varepsilon$.

Here, the idea is that after $N$, the series is bounded by $1 -\varepsilon$ and $1 + \varepsilon$ and there is a finite number of values that $(a_n)$ takes for $n < N$

So we can conclude that :

$$ \min\left(\lbrace a_n, n \lt N\rbrace \cup \lbrace 1 - \varepsilon \rbrace \right) \leq a_n \leq \max\left(\lbrace a_n, n \lt N\rbrace \cup \lbrace 1 + \varepsilon \rbrace \right) $$

You mentioned in your question the sequence $\left(1 + 1/n \right)^n$, but it converges to the Euler constant $e$, not to $1$. You can see it by writing the terms in exponential notation.

Also, your idea to find a bounding series $b_n$ will be difficult to work with because you almost don't know anything about $a_n$.

Finally, the idea that if two series converge towards the same limit, one will overtake the other is false.

To see this you just need to consider a series $(\alpha_n)$ converging towards $0$ by "oscillating" around $0$. For example, take

$$ \alpha_n = \frac{\sin(n)}{n + 1} $$

So now if you take any series $(a_n)$ converging towards a limit $x$, the sequence $(a_n + \alpha_n)$ also converges towards $x$ but one never overtakes the other since $(\alpha_n)$ is alternatively positive, then negative, and so on.